# How to handle dataTable.Rows.Clear() event in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, datatable

I cant figure out how to handle `dataTable.Rows.Clear()` event, it is not captured by both `dataTable.RowDeleted` nor by `dataTable.RowChanged`. I would like to capture the event AFTER all rows have been cleared from the table. Thanks

Comment: `dataTable.Rows.Clear()` is a method not an event. it cannot be captured but could be called. It will clear all rows collection.

Comment: Understood, but is this method when called firing some event that could be captured?

Comment: You don't need an event.  You know when it happens when you call that code.

Comment: @Jeanno you're explaining things very unclear but the event you're looking for is `TableCleared` :)

Comment: How are you intending to call dataTable.Rows.Clear()? Can you show some code? It's not clear why you can't just do whatever you want directly after calling that method as you know it's been called.

Answer (score 1):

By the follow code snippet you can achieve the handling of the `Rows.Clear()` event.

Assign a handler to `TableCleared`

```
dt.TableCleared += dt_TableCleared;

void dt_TableCleared(object sender, DataTableClearEventArgs e)
{
    // your code
}
```

Hope this code will help you!

Comment: I directly edited your answer and forgot to add an edit summary. It's just a copy-edit to better conform to english standards of the site. Hope you don't mind.